# Any point in learning WPF when Metro is coming out in Win 8?

Tags: wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

If you haven't already done so, is there any point in learning WPF when the Metro language is coming out in Win 8?

Comment: AFAIK UI would be built usig XAML but I'm not sure about WPF

Comment: For Metro development, XAML knowledge (part of WPF) can be used. For Desktop development, AFAIK you can still run the WPF software on Win8 desktop.

Comment: WPF is Microsoft's go-to desktop UI technology. There remain MANY applications better served on the desktop than in Metro. For now.

Answer (score 3):

Metro UIs can be built with C# and XAML. So if you learn WPF, most of that knowledge will be transferable to Metro development.